# What is going on when I play a video from a share on another computer?

Tags: windows, file-sharing

Lets say the file `video.mp4` lives on `server1`. Using `computer1` I navigate to `\\server1\shared\video.mp4` and play the video. I did not save the video file to `computer1` and then play it, so is Windows actually streaming the video from `server1` to `computer1`?

Also, if a lot of simultaneous users played the video from the share, does that put any additional load on `server1` or is it all handled on the computers that connected to the shared file?

Comment: " Windows actually streaming the video from server1 to computer1?" Yes

Comment: The file server acts to host the video file and handles the network load allowing the file to be streamed to each client.  The clients only handle receiving their respective copies of the file streams and render it within their respective video players for themselves.  The clients don't help each other in this scenario.